# Creating a new column in panda using logical slicing and group by by different columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a data frame like below

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','a','b','a','a','a'], 'b' :        [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1], 'c' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'d':['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2']})
df
Out[94]:
    a   b   c   d
0   a   1   1   1
1   a   0   2   2
2   b   0   3   1
3   a   1   4   2
4   b   0   5   1
5   a   1   6   2
6   a   1   7   1
7   a   1   8   2
```

In [97]:

```
df[(df['a']=='a') & (df['b']==1)].groupby('d')['c'].

Out[97]:
    a   b   c   d   sum
0   a   1   1   1   8
1   a   0   2   2   NaN
2   b   0   3   1   NaN
3   a   1   4   2   18
4   b   0   5   1   NaN
5   a   1   6   2   18
6   a   1   7   1   8
7   a   1   8   2   18
dtype: float64
```

I want this sum  as a new column in dataframe df . SO final output will be something like below

```
    a   b   c   d  sum
0   a   1   1   1  8
1   a   0   2   2  18
2   b   0   3   1  8
3   a   1   4   2  18
4   b   0   5   1  8
5   a   1   6   2  18
6   a   1   7   1  8
7   a   1   8   2  18
```

I will appreciate all the help and guidance. Thanks a lot.
If I have to do this in SQl the query will be something like below
Select
*
from df
inner join 
       (Select
              'd'
              ,sum( case when 'a'=1 & 'b'= 1 then 'c' else null end) sum
        from df
        group by
        df
        ) inner
on df.'d' = inner.'d'
I will like to avoid merge if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
In [30]:
mask = np.logical_and( df['a'] == 'a' , df['b'] == 1 )
mask
Out[30]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

In [32]:
df['sum'] = df.groupby(df.d)['c'].transform(lambda x : x[mask].sum())
df
Out[32]:
    a   b   c   d   sum
0   a   1   1   1   8
1   a   0   2   2   18
2   b   0   3   1   8
3   a   1   4   2   18
4   b   0   5   1   8
5   a   1   6   2   18
6   a   1   7   1   8
7   a   1   8   2   18
```

Comment: Hello Nader, thanks a lot for taking some time and answering to my question. however I do not get desired result. I do get   8,NaN,NaN,18,NaN,18,8,18 instead of 8,18,18,8,18. I tried below code
    df['sum']=df[(df['a']=='a') & (df['b']==1)].groupby('d')['c'].transform(lambda x : x.sum())

Comment: I didn't get your question at first check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Nader. I have to do some research about mask function but this works great. Thanks